# Does this probability problem make sense?

Tags: probability

I just got a probability problem as follows.

> Every person in a region has a probability of getting infected by HIV
>   of 0.1. If the total population of that region is 1000 persons, find
>   how many person approximately get infected?

What I don't understand is how the probability for each person correlate to the population. Is this problem correct? I don't know  which concept to be applied here. Independent event, mutually exclusive event, etc,... I am really confused!

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity, but I assume the question intends for you to see that with probability 0.1, a person is infected by HIV where the probability of each person getting infected is independent of each other. So the number of people infected is the expected value of a binomial distribution where $n = 1000$ and $p = 0.1$. Then the answer is simply $np = 100$.

Another way to see this is to define a random variable $X_{i}\sim Ber(0.1)$ where $X_{i} = 1$ if the $i$th person is infected or $0$ otherwise. Then by linearity of the expected value,

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_{i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}\mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{1000}0.1 = 1000(0.1)$$

Comment: Please tell me the some ambiguities you meant.

Comment: Well. Are they independent? What does having a chance of being infected mean? At each time $t$, does a healthy person have a chance of becoming infected? Or is it saying that if you select a random person from a group of 1000, with probability $p$ they have HIV? I think given reasonable assumptions with the information available, the interpretation I gave is a reasonable one.

Comment: The sum of Bernoulli argument is better, because the linearity of expectation does not require independence. However, it is quite possible that in this problem, OP is expected to assume independence (so Binomial) despite its implausibility.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you elaborate? I feel like they are the same because I cannot reasonably define my random variables $X_{i}$ in this fashion without implicitly assuming independence.

Comment: Your *definition* of the $X_i$ did not assume independence, it is a perfectly general argument.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Central limit theorem** to do the approximation.
[Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)